# Hide the first submenu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm working on a site with the following menu structure:

```
<ul class="menu">
<li><a href="#">Home</a>
    <ul class="submenu">
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>

<li><a href="#">About Us</a>
    <ul class="submenu">
        <li><a href="#">Mission Statement</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
</ul>
```

How would I go about hiding the first submenu?

Answer (score 3):

Try css :first-child

```
.menu li:first-child ul {
    display:none;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

jQuery

```
$('.submenu').first().hide()
```

to whoever downvoted this answer: have you tried it yourself? [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/SfbPP/)

Comment: i tried it and ofcourse it works,i don't know why they have downvoted,+1

Answer (score 1):

You can use [.first()](http://api.jquery.com/first/) filter out first element from the matching set

```
jQuery(function($){
    $('.menu').find('.submenu').first().hide()
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/tEdQu/)

Answer (score 1):

You can simply do it using jQuery like this :

```
$('ul.submenu').first().hide();
```

Specifically:

```
$('ul.menu ul.submenu').first().hide();
```

Comment: This will hide all elements with class `submenu`. The OP wants to hide the first only.

Comment: sorry i forgot the first

Answer (score 0):

You can also use css `:first-child`:

```
.menu li:first-child .submenu {
   display:none;
}
```

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/KTNe8/1/

Comment: your css hides all submenus